# Conditional expectation property prove

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Prove that if $E(Y|X) = X$ and $E(Y^2|X) = X^2$ than $Y$ and $X$ coincide everywhere
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKK07.png)

Comment: No, they coincide a.s., $\mathbb{E}(X-Y)^2=0$. What do you think, why?

Comment: Can you give me a hint for solving this problem please?

Comment: I did, actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider
$$E((Y-X)^2 | X) = E(Y^2 - 2 YX + X^2|X) = E(Y^2|X) - 2 X E(Y|X) + X^2 = X^2 - 2X \cdot X + X^2 = 0,$$
thus $E(Y-X)^2  =E ( E((Y-X)^2|X)) =0 $. It follows that $Y=X$ a.s.